# htaccess redirect from www to non-www inside subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I dont have access to the web server root directory and I need to redirect calls from www.mydomain.com/folder1/folder2 to http://mydomain.com/folder1/folder2.

I tried to write to .htaccess the following:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com/folder1/folder2[nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.com/folder1/folder2/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

I placed it inside folder2, it didnt work, what do I need to change for it to work?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [L,R=302]
```

It is checking to see if it is `www.` and if it is, then redirect it to `http://domain.com`

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^folde/dopl$ http://domain.com/folde/dopl [L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^folde/dopl/(.*)$ http://domain.com/folde/dopl/$1 [L,R=302]
```

Comment: does this work inside subfolders? because I tried it and it still take me to www.

Answer (score 0):

%{HTTP_HOST} only contains the domain (`mydomain.com`). Also, your condition only applies to a host which already is missing the www. And the dots need to be escaped.

So your RewriteCond should be:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.com [NC]
```

Also, your RewriteRule captures the whole request string (including /folder1/folder2), the the rule redirects to /folder1/folder2/folder1/folder2.

See answer of Howlin for a correct attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.mydomain\.com)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.com/folder1/folder2/$1 [R=301,L]
```

By the way, if you are using 301 redirect, your browser may cache the redirect, so clear the cache before testing again!

Reference:
https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25775/subfolder-non-www-redirect